# select and skip MySQL results

Tags: mysql

I have a database with information about games. There are categories assigned to each game in the form cat1, cat2, cat3.
The structure of my table

```
games (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar (100) not null,
    ...
    cats varchar (200) not null,
    FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext (cats)
    primary key (id)
)engine=myisam charset=utf8;
```

To search for games from a specific category I use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE MATCH(cats) AGAINST('action' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Now, how can I display games that do not contain the "action" category ?
For example, I want to display all games that do not contain "action" words in the cats field.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think you need to normalize your data. Create another table `game_to_cat` and store `game_id` and `cat_id` there, instead of storing them as a comma separated value here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NOT operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM game
WHERE cat1 NOT IN ('action');
```

of in your case would probably be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games 
WHERE NOT MATCH(cats) AGAINST('action' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

documentation:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE cats  NOT LIKE '%action%'
```

When I put multiple values in on field I try to separat them with special separators not comma.

Like this : ##cat1##cat2##cat3##

So when I need to search I can do this :

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE cats LIKE '%##action##%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE cats NOT LIKE '%##action##%'
```

But as  @Madhur Bhaiya sad, you need to restructure you'r data. 
This is not the optimal datastructure.